# Tohoku and cohomology of toposes

Tags: homological-algebra, soft-question, ho.history-overview, cohomology, topos-theory

In McLarty's *The Rising Sea: Grothendieck on simplicity and generality* I found the following quote:

> The same, Grothendieck knew, would work for cases yet unimagined. He notes that Tohoku [Grothendieck 1957] already gave foundations for the cohomology of any topos [Grothendieck 1985–1987, p. P41n.]. That context was hardly foreseen as he wrote Tohoku in 1955. This is one more proof that it was the right idea of cohomology.

In which sense gave Tohoku a foundation for the cohomology of any topos? In particular, which theorem in Tohoku proves or constructs the cohomology of toposes?

[Grothendieck 1985–1987, p. P41n.] is *Récoltes et Semailles*. (I can spot the passage in which Grothendieck refers to Tohoku, but this doesn't answer my question.)

I could swear I heard the claim before that Tohoku is the *only* place in the literature which shows that toposes have cohomology (of course without mentioning the word "topos"), although I can't recall at the moment where I heard that.

Comment: Maybe this is referring to the fact that Tohoku establishes that what we now call Grothendieck abelian categories have enough injectives. Sheaves of abelian groups on a (Grothendieck) topos form a Grothendieck abelian category, hence have enough injectives, so one can take derived functors of global sections

Comment: I suspect Dylan Wilson's comment is the answer. However, the claim that Tohoku is the *only* place... seems pretty dubious, cf SGA4 exp. V.

Comment: I would also not say that Tohoku was the only place... but I think your question is the topic of this [talk](https://alainconnes.org/2017/11/un-topo-sur-les-topos/), (or [here](http://denisevellachemla.eu/mai13a.pdf)).

Comment: @scritoriano I can't speak French. Can you translate some points which are relevant to my question?

Comment: I agree too with @DylanWilson that the comment refers to the existence of injectives on a Grothendieck category. I suggest to post its as an answer.

Comment: I think that topos were defined precisely so that cohomology had a sense for them... This seems a rather vacuous assertion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As requested:

By Theorem 1.10.1 in Tohoku, an Grothendieck abelian category has enough injectives. Sheaves of abelian groups on a Grothendieck topos form a Grothendieck abelian category. By Theorem 2.2.2 in Tohoku, one may then take derived functors of global sections.

As mentioned in the comments, though, sheaf cohomology on toposes is developed quite a bit elsewhere (e.g. in SGA 4).

Comment: Thanks! Are derived functors due to Grothendieck?

Comment: @user469007 I think they are due to Cartan-Eilenberg

Comment: @user469007 I think Cartan-Eilenberg are responsible for derived functors in the category of modules over a ring. Grothendieck for the more general version.